# How to convert month year (YYYYmm) string to Datetime in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, datetime-format

I have a Year and Month string `"202008"` which I need to convert into DateTime like `2020-08-01 00:00:00`. What would be the best way to do it using Javascript or Momentjs?

Comment: Does it always become the first day of the month? Also you put `YYYYmm` in the title, but the example string is `mmYYYY`

Comment: "Best" by what criteria? In POJS it's a simple find/replace using a regular expression, using a date library requires parsing and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JS

```js
function toDate(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\d\d)(\d{4})/, "$2-$1-01 00:00:00");
}
console.log(toDate("082020"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the input format in `moment` by using the [second argument](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).
`moment(input, format)`

```
moment('082020', 'MY').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// 2020-08-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: If you're going to use a 3rd party lib, [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is also worth considering (a lot of people prefer it to `moment` due to its smaller size)